# Casting a Float Array

Tags: java, arrays, floating-point

I've been writing Java for a while and have even been starting to teach it to others. I find it hard to explain to a new student why a float array's values must be casted. For example:

```
float[] someArray = {(float) 23.23, (float) 123.1, (float) 123.1};  
int[] intArray = {12, 13, 4, 5};
double[] doubleArray = {22.12, 23.1, 12.1};
```

I'm guessing that the the values that include decimals are just treated as Doubles rather than floats, hence the need for casting. What is the reason that Java chooses it to be this way, couldn't the compiler also figure that because it is a float array, it will take float values?

Comment: `float f = 23.23f;`

Comment: A "raw" decimal value defaults to `double`, hence you must specify a float if you want to use it as such. Either via a cast as you do, or as a float literal as Scary Wombat suggests. The compiler _could_ assume you meant `float`, but that might not be what you want, hence the warning/error.

Comment: Unlike a conversion from a wider integer type to a narrower integer type, a conversion from `double` to `float` can change the value, because the `double` value must be rounded to fit in the `float` precision. So I presume the Java designers do not allow implicit `double` to `float` conversions to avoid this change in value without an explicit request by the programmer. The specific rules for conversions allowed for assignments are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), but I am not familiar enough with the Java specification to interpret it readily and…

Comment: … say whether those are the specific rules that govern the specific code you ask about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numbers with decimal points in Java are implicitly treated as `double`. Instead of casting to a float, you can simply write `23.23F`, for example. The `F` at the end tells the compiler to treat the value as a `float` literal.